# Data generation in Excel

Tags: excel

Good morning, I am new at using excel and I'll be very thankful if someone can help (and I'm sure that the answer is easy from your point of view).

https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/785039data.png

The screen capture reprents a simplified way of explaining what I am looking for:

For each number in the first column (which can appear more than once), I want to generate a corresponding Id (See column Id to affect which is the type of data).
We are only looking at the beginning of "Number", which can be up to 8 number is size.
Sometimes there can be tricky case, as te example starting with 40 vs 402 which are not affected to the same Id.

As I am new on excel maybe this answer or question exist but I don't know how to search/name it.
Thank you for your help, have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky formula. Not exactly the prettiest thing ever but this formula works: (Line breaks added for readability)

```
= IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$7,MATCH(MAX((((A2-(C$2:C$7*10^(CEILING(LOG10(A2+1),1)
  -CEILING(LOG10(C$2:C$7+1),1))))=MOD(A2,10^(CEILING(LOG10(A2+1),1)
  -CEILING(LOG10(C$2:C$7+1),1))))+0)*C$2:C$7),C$2:C$7,0)),"(no match)")
```

A few things to note:

1. You didn't include cell ranges so you will have to manually change the cell ranges in the formula above to whatever your particular cell ranges are.
2. This is an array formula, meaning after you enter this formula into a cell, you must press on the keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. The formula looks for the "strongest" match. For example, if a number is 40200000, the formula would return "Grapefruit" because it is a stronger match than "Grape".
4. If no match is found, I just have the formula return "(no match)" but you can obviously change that to whatever you want.
5. I assume this won't be an issue, but the formula will not work if any negative numbers are used.

See below, screenshot that shows formula works for your data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your promt answer !
I'm trying to make this work now, but failed. I forgot to mention that I'm using Excel 2010, is it different ?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 also. Did you change all of the cell ranges to whatever your ranges are and enter it as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)?

Comment: I'm first trying with exactly the same example as you posted.

Comment: Again as I said in the original post... your question didn't include specific cell ranges so you will have to change the cell ranges to whatever the actual cell ranges are in your sheet.

Comment: I used the same data as your example.
When I press Ctrl  Shift Enter, just the error popup appear, I tried with the same formula (Copy pasted), and without line return and spaces as well.

Comment: Once again... **your question didn't include specific cell ranges so you will have to change the cell ranges in my formula to whatever the actual cell ranges are in your sheet**.

Comment: As the example, I use C2 to C7 and D2 to D7.

Comment: Are the "part numbers" in the A column? If all of those ranges are correct, the formula will work. I included screenshot to show that the formula works.

Comment: I loose some hair but manage to understand why it didn't worked, there it is if other people need it: I use excel in another language, and don't use same separators (difference between commas and semi colons). So most of English formulas works in english but not everything. I used a language formula translator and now it's working ! Thank you ImaginaryHuman072889 for all your help !

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I always wondered why some questions on this website used colons as separators instead of commas. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can try this array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) from `cell B2` and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$7,MATCH(MAX((VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN($C$2:$C$7)))=$C$2:$C$7)*C$2:C$7),C$2:C$7,0)),"")
```

This will try to match the longest number (with `MAX`) and return the value (with `INDEX/MATCH`).

Comment: Ha, better solution than mine. I used a convoluted formula with `LOG10` to determine how many digits a number was instead of merely using the `LEN` function. Didn't know until now that `LEN` worked with numbers. I thought it only worked with strings. Good to know for future use.

Comment: I have that effect on people... (sarcasm). Actually I guess using the `LOG10` method would be useful for numbers with a decimal point, but in this case with whole numbers it's easier.